# Running files-NetworkX is missing

Tags: boolean, networkx

I am working with BooleanNet1.2.7 in Ubuntu and I am trying to run the file "all-initial-states.py", but I am facing problems. I have Python2.7 and I have installed all the other packages needed for such scripts. The problem is that when I run this file it shows an error message " networkx is missing", however I have networkx installed. I don't know how to solve it. Has anyone faced the same problem as me? Thanks!

Comment: How did you install networkx ? `import networkx` is giving you an ImportError ?

Comment: I used: pip install networkx.
However, I am sure I have networkx installed because I run some other files and it doesn't give any error. I suppose the problem is when I run files which use boolean modeling but I don't understand why.

Comment: You are getting this error because if I remember correctly, the file `networks.py` in the BooleanNet has a statement to try importing networkx. The exception you specified is thrown from there. The other files you tried executing, are they importing networkx ?

Comment: You're probably right but I can't say this for sure because I am new in this area and I have just started to learn. The other files I execute don't import networkx. To be more specific, the file I'm trying to execute begeins in this way:
"import boolean2
from boolean2 import util, state, network"
As far as I understand, the problem is at network in which there is this beginning:
import util
import random
from itertools import count
try:
    import networkx
 #   from networkx import component
except ImportError:
    util.error( "networkx is missing, install it from https://networkx.lanl.gov/")